# How to open PDF file in Cordova/Ionic app?

Tags: cordova, pdf, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm trying to open a PDF file in my app which I'm building with [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/). I understand that I can do that using the inAppBrowser.

I first get the PDF from an api endpoint, after which I write it to the filesystem. Once it is written to the file system, I want to open it using the [inAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). The code I have now is as follows:

```
$http.get(window.apiUrl + '/doc/54bfcc7b879c686969d2bbfe')
    .success(function(data){
        console.log('PDF GOTTEN SUCCESFULLY. NOW WRITE IT TO A FILE.');
        $cordovaFile.writeFile('ticket.pdf', data, true)
            .then(function (success) {
                console.log('PDF WAS WRITTEN TO THE FILE SYSTEM');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(success));
                $cordovaFile.readAsText('ticket.pdf')
                    .then(function (data) {
                        console.log('PDF COULD BE READ FROM THE SYSTEM');
                        window.open('cdvfile://localhost/persistent/ticket.pdf', '_system', 'location=no');
                        console.log('AFTER OPENING THE PDF');
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                    });
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    })
    .error(function(error){
        console.log('IMAGE GET FAILURE.');
    });
```

I get no errors whatsoever in the console, but nothing happens in the screen. The output I see in the console.log is as follows:

```
file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js: Line 104 : PDF GOTTEN SUCCESFULLY. NOW WRITE IT TO A FILE.
file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js: Line 110 : PDF WAS WRITTEN TO THE FILE SYSTEM
file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js: Line 111 : {"type":"writeend","bubbles":false,"cancelBubble":false,"cancelable":false,"lengthComputable":false,"loaded":0,"total":0,"target":{"fileName":"","length":598874,"localURL":"cdvfile://localhost/persistent/ticket.pdf","position":598874,"readyState":2,"result":null,"error":null,"onwritestart":null,"onprogress":null,"onwrite":null,"onabort":null,"onerror":null}}
file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js: Line 115 : PDF COULD BE READ FROM THE SYSTEM
file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js: Line 119 : AFTER OPENING THE PDF
```

As you can see I hardcoded the ticket name (`ticket.pdf`) and the path when opening it up (`cdvfile://localhost/persistent/ticket.pdf`). The file path I got from the json success-output as displayed in the output on line 111 (see above).

Does anbody know why this isn't working? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The url cdvfile://localhost/persistent/ticket.pdf is not the correct one. You will need a nativeurl path starting with file://.

try these:

'file:///storage/emulated/0/ticket.pdf'
or
'file:///storage/sdcard0/ticket.pdf'